# Display Attachment image in formula field

Tags: formula-field, image-formula

I have a trigger which updates attachment id into a custom field of object `X__c`. I have creatted a formula field with below formula to display the attached pic

```
IMAGE('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=customfield__c', customfield__c ,20,20).
```

But the image is not getting displayed.But if i replace the `customfield__c` with attachment id like below , the image is getting displayed. Please help where i am going wrong.

```
IMAGE('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P28000000Ezg4', customfield__c ,20,20).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you've enclosed `customfield__c` inside single quotes it is being treated as a string literal in your formula.

You need to remove it from the single quotes and instead append it to your string to get the result you want.

```
IMAGE('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + customfield__c, customfield__c, 20, 20)
```

Comment: Thanx Alex.. U r genious..Thanx again....